# $X^3-X-1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I need to show that $f=X^3-X-1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. But reduction modulo $3$ gives $f_3=X^3+X+1$ and $f_3(1)=0$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Reduction mod $3$ is $x^3-x-1$ and this has no zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_3$ so it is irreducible and you are done. If it makes things easier for you, you can think of $x^3+2x+2$ as the reduction, as $-1\equiv2\pmod3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, often times in my book the reduction modulo changes "-" into "+". So that's not correct?

Comment: It is correct to ignore the sign if and only if you are reducing modulo two. Modulo two we have $1+1=0$ implying that $-1=+1$. More generally $-1=p-1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that you can already see it has not zero in $\mathbb{Q}$ because since it's a monic polynomial a root would have to be an integer dividing the constant coefficient, so it can only be $1$ or $-1$ (which are not roots).

Comment: Just a last question: $X^4 +9X^2 −2X +2$ reduced modulo $3$ would be $X^4-2X+2$?

Comment: Correct. But if you prefer you can say that it is also $x^4+x-1$. Because $2\equiv-1\pmod3$ they are interchangeable. As are $1\equiv-2$.

Answer (score 1):

If a cubic polynomial is reducible, at least one of the factors must be linear. But the only possible rational roots are integer divisors of $-1$, i.e. $\pm 1$. Substituting into the given polynomial, we see that neither $1$ nor $-1$ is a root. So the polynomial has no linear factor and thus is irreducible.